# React Native Multiple Images Picker

Tags: react-native, expo

**The problem**

So, I am developing a react native application and I am facing the callenge of selecting multiple images from the user gallery. Just like apps like WhatsApp, Telegram, Twitter and even Reddit do. So with that in mind, i tried to use [launchImageLibraryAsync](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/#imagepickerlaunchimagelibraryasyncoptions) from [expo-image-picker](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker) but, as specified in their documentation, the "multiple selecion" of images is only supported on the web.

**What I have thinked of**

So, based on several searches, it seemed like i had to build my own "Gallery". To do this, so far i've tried to use [@react-native-community/cameraroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/cameraroll#getphotos) and [expo-media-library](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/media-library), but **both of them** requires that we pass the `first` property to the getPhotos (for @react-native-community/cameraroll) or to the getAssetsAsync (for expo-media-library) functions, which defines the first items to be fetched. This is a problem because I do not want to fetch like 20 items and then, when the user reaches the end of the list, it fetches more 20 items. I need something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w8FudJCQH3s) (this example is from Telegram). You can see that the app never stops me from scrolling, it goes all the way through my entire gallery.

**What would also be nice**

If you use reddit mobile, you can see that you can also [select multiple photos using the several Apps like Google Photos, Files, Google Drive and so on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRGqN.jpg).

This would be even nicer because I wouldn't need to implement a custom made Picker. Do you guys know how could I implement this?

OBS: I am using Expo with Bare Workflow, so I can use just about any package. I also opened a discussion at the Expo repo about it. You can check it here: https://github.com/expo/expo/discussions/15210.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score -1):

I have been using this package called `expo-images-picker` check it out. It has similar function to what you need. It works in Mobile as well.

Link [here](https://github.com/natysoz/expo-images-picker)

Comment: I don't know if it would work in my case because I also need to allow the user to select an album if they want to. Also, unfortunately it seems like this package presents the same problem I mentioned above, which is when I reach the end of the list of the mentioned current "page", it fetches more items (most of the times this presents lagging when selecting an image while the next "page" is being fetched). I would like my list to be like Telegram or WhatsApp. In these apps I can scroll all the way through my entire gallery/recent items/all media. Like [this](https://youtu.be/w8FudJCQH3s).